# Best way to prevent ActiveRecord association validations on specific actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, associations

I have 2 models: `User` and `Purchase`. Purchases belong to Users.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :purchases
end
```

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  enum status: %i[succeeded pending failed refunded]
end
```

In Rails 5.2, a validation error is raised when any modifications are made to a `Purchase` with no associated `User`. This works great for new purchases, but it also throws errors when simply trying to save data on an existing purchase with a user that no longer exists in the database.

For example:

```
user = User.find(1)

# Fails because no user is passed
purchase = Purchase.create(status: 'succeeded') 

# Succeeds
purchase = Purchase.create(user: user, status: 'succeeded') 
purchase.status = 'failed'
purchase.save

user.destroy

# Fails because user doesn't exist
purchase.status = 'refunded'
purchase.save
```

I know I can prevent the second update from failing by making the association optional with `belongs_to :user, optional: true` in the purchase model, but that cancels out the first validation for purchase creation as well.

I could also just build my own custom validations for the user association, but I'm looking for a more conventional Rails way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use validation contexts https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

You can make the relationship optional and then add a validation only on create but not on update (default behaviour is on save):

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true

validates :user, presence: true, on: :create
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if:` and `unless:` options to make validations conditional:

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true # suppress generation of the default validation
  validates_presence_of :user, unless: :refunded?
  enum status: %i[succeeded pending failed refunded]
end
```

You can pass the name of a method or a lambda. These shouldn't be confused with the `if` and `unless` keywords - they are just keyword arguments.

The `optional:` option for `belongs_to` really just adds a `validates_presence_of` validation with no options. Which is nice as a shorthand but not really that flexible.